# Change geom_bar width default to another default

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, bar-chart, ggproto

**What I want to do**

I currently have a custom theme for my plots, and I want to have on top of that some predefined parameters for all type of plots. My first focus is on bar charts, where I want to change the default width.

The default width of geom_bar in ggplot2 is "*By default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data.*" (http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html).

I'd like to change that default to **75%**. To be clear, I am **not** interested in changing it like this:

`geom_bar(stat='identity', width=0.75)`

Because that would mean I have to specify it everytime I create a bar chart. I want it to be the new default.

**What I tried so far**

I tried to change the width default using this:

`update_geom_defaults("bar", list(width=0.75))`

But then I get an error message: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (964): width`. I'm thinking this might be due to the fact that the width is calculated based on the resolution of the data, which is not yet there at the moment I call `update_geom_defaults`

Plus, I also realised that `width` is not part of the default aes of the bars :

```
GeomBar$default_aes
* colour   -> NA
* fill     -> "grey35"
* size     -> 0.5
* linetype -> 1
* alpha    -> NA
```

**My questions are:**

- Where is that 90% default set?
- Can I change it in any way?
- If not, is there another way to pass a predefined set of parameters to all the geom_* functions?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default is defined in [`GeomBar`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-bar.r):

```
GeomBar <- ggproto("GeomBar", GeomRect,
  required_aes = c("x", "y"),

  setup_data = function(data, params) {
    data$width <- data$width %||%
      params$width %||% (resolution(data$x, FALSE) * 0.9)  ## <- right here
    transform(data,
      ymin = pmin(y, 0), ymax = pmax(y, 0),
      xmin = x - width / 2, xmax = x + width / 2, width = NULL
    )
  },

  draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_params, coord, width = NULL) {
    # Hack to ensure that width is detected as a parameter
    ggproto_parent(GeomRect, self)$draw_panel(data, panel_params, coord)
  }
)
```

The marked line uses `%||%`, which is used to set a default in the event `params$width` is `NULL` (which is the default in `geom_bar`, `NULL` means "set it to something reasonable for me").

There is no nice way like `update_geom_defaults` to change this. What you can do, is make your own `geom_bar` like this:

```
geom_bar75 <- function (..., width = 0.75) {
  geom_bar(..., width = width)
}
```

This will work just fine in most cases, i.e. with a discrete x-axis (because the resolution is then 1). For more complicated cases you may need to adjust, or redefine `GeomBar` itself.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar75()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Thanks!